# Trying to link to an external static library. But QT creator is compiling the external library source files

Tags: c++, qt-creator, static-libraries

This is all happening on Ubuntu 18.04, with QT creator 4.5.2.  The project is a QT widget project. I want to link to a statically linked C++ library created in netbeans. But when I build,
QT Creator doesn't just link to the static library, it compiles a file in the library (game.cpp) and generates the following error.

> /home/bobp040653/Scrabble/Programming/ScrabbleLib/Game.cpp:9: error: undefined reference to `ScrabbleLib::Game::TileBag::tileValues'

I don't understand this at all. Game.o is part of the external statically linked library.
It compiles just fine under netbeans.  Is it because the library is libscrabblelib.a?
Is that a library type that QT doesn't understand?

Here's a copy of the .pro file for my project.

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2020-03-03T10:32:12
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TipTopQTW
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        tiptop.cpp

HEADERS += \
        tiptop.h

FORMS += \
        tiptop.ui

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../ScrabbleLib/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/ -lscrabblelib

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../ScrabbleLib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../ScrabbleLib

unix:!macx: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../ScrabbleLib/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/libscrabblelib.a
```

Answer (score 0):

You added `DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../ScrabbleLib`, which says to Qt to compile the files.

Comment: I commented the DEPENDPATH out , but the build system still builds Game.cpp.  I did notice that it builds Game.o and Game.d. I'm thinking that Game.d is a dependency file.  Does anyone know what Game.d is?  When netbeans builds the library it doesn't create the .d files. I'd love to know what's happening here.